# Drupal get parameters from url in edit form and populate the form

Tags: php, drupal, forms

i have an employee table with fields like id, name, age and salary.

Iam showing the list of employee names in my custom module and when i click on an employee name, i have to show the edit form of that employee.

The employee names are given a link, as like:

```
<a href='".$base_url."/my_module/edit/".$employee->id."'>
```

and the corresponding menu path is configured as:

```
$items['my_module/edit/%'] = array(
        'title' => t('My form'),
        'description' => t('Edit employee'),
        'page callback' => 'my_module_edit',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,        
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
```

And when i click on the 5th employee name, the url would be: **..../my_module/edit/5**

So now my questions are:

1. How can i get the id (5) of the employee from the url in my **my_module_edit** function ?
2. How can i show the edit form of the employee, populating the fields (by querying with id) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question 2: You have got it mixed up a bit, you don't create a custom 'page callback' menu item for forms, you should use 'drupal_get_form' as the 'page callback' with the name of your form() function (my_module_employee_form) as the 'page arguments'.

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['my_module/employee/edit/%'] = array(
     'title' => t('Edit employee'),
     'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
     'page arguments' => array('my_module_employee_form', 3),
     'access arguments' => array('administer my_module'),
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
   );
 }

function my_module_employee_form() {
  ... read database and generate form..
}

function my_module_employee_form_submit($form_id, &$form) {
  ... read form and update database ...
}
```

Then in the function my_module_employee_form() you generate the form and populate it, and in  my_module_employee_form_submit() you read the values back and store them in the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
$request_parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI');
$employee_id = intval(array_pop($request_parts));
```

That's for your question #1.  Not sure I understand #2

Comment: #2 is that: I have to show the employee add form in edit mode. The form has fields id, name, age and salary. So i have to query the employees table with the id and get the values and populate the form with these values.

Comment: I guess I don't have enough information to answer #2.  Or maybe I don't know enough about Drupal.  If I knew the database table structure I could show you the MySQL way to do it, but not sure about the "correct" Drupal way.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you can get the arguments passed to a callback by using arg(0), arg(1), arg(2) etc...

```
<a href='".$base_url."/my_module/edit/".$employee->id."'>
```

For this href arg(0) == 'my_module', arg(1) == 'edit', arg(2) == '5', take a look at [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6)'s documentation.

You can also parse the query string your self by accessing the $_GET['q'] variable.

For your second question, if your employee table is a Drupal table you can just make the link be the edit link to the Drupal node, like href="node/5/edit". If it is a custom table you will have to create your own form by implementing [hook_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--node.php/function/hook_form/6)

Comment: Thanks zeropage. Myne is a custom table, and so i implemented hook_form() and in that method, i am returning my form: **return drupal_get_form('my_module_my_form');** But how to populate it?

Comment: Just populate it from your custom queries;

$form['my_field'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => t('Some database field'), 
    '#default_value' => 'some database value'
  );`

Comment: You should read this http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api/6, because when you are going to save your form data into a custom table you will need to override hook_form_submit() as well.